# Keeping application.properties up to date

Tags: spring, maven, properties

So historically, we launch our Spring application using the maven command and explicitly specifying the active profile of the application. At the root of the project, we have two .properties files:

- `local-application.properties`, in which the settings for the local
  environment are located and which are not monitored by git;
- `application.properties.template`, which stores settings for the
  dev environment.

When adding a new functionality, you may need new properties that the developer may forget to add to `application.properties.template`, which is why the `dev` environment will not start, because the person responsible for this will not know anything about these new properties.

*In this regard, the question is:*

> Is it possible to use maven to automate a reminder to the developer to
>   add the necessary properties or their values ​​to the `application.properties.template` file,
>   if such changes take place?

It may be possible to break all property values ​​across new *.options files and then, when performing any of the maven phases (for example, verify), generate this .template file.

Or maybe there is some kind of plugin that does similar things.

Thanks!

Comment: you can use git hooks. in a pre-commit hook md5sum the file and compare it with previous md5sum. If previous file is missing or checksum is different & . template is older, echo to update and exit non-zero int, the commit will fail.  
or generate it instead of failing